# Python dictionary reseting outside of loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I am building a creature simulator. It will run inside two for loops one keeping track of day, and one keeping track of time of day. I have a dictionary of all my creatures called awake, it is set at the start of each day. At some point during the time of day loop a creature will become tired and go to sleep. The simulation removes them from the awake dictionary so that they will not be considered for the remaining time of day loops. But here is the problem, for some reason the awake dictionary resets with every time of day loop so that the sleeping creatures are accessed. I have posted the relevant code here, this is the only time awake is used. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
        for i in range(self.Day):
            start = clock()
            awake = self.creatures
            for j in range(self.timeOfDay):          
                print("Life Time " + str(i + 1) + "/" + str(self.Day) 
                       + " Hour " + str(j + 1) + "/" + str(self.timeOfDay))
                print(self)
                traveling = []
                for creature in awake:
                    goal = None
                    while goal == None:
                        priority = creature.priority()
                        if priority == "improveShelter":
                            goal = creature.findBest(land.Shelter, self.map)
                        elif priority == "sleep":
                            goal = creature.findBest(land.Shelter, self.map)
                            print(awake)
                            awake.pop(creature)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of each day you need to make a copy of the `creatures`dict instead of referencing it:

```
awake = dict(self.creatures)
```

This is a quite common pitfall with all kinds of mutable types in Python.

Python only has references to object, not something like a "variable". So writing `a=b` just creates a new reference named `a` to the same object already referenced by `b`.

Comment: Woops. Looks like I temporarily forgot that python uses references.

Answer (score 6):

You are looping over `awake` and modifying it at the same time. This means that certain items are going to be *skipped*.

Create a *copy* of `awake` instead to disconnect the loop iterator from `awake` so you can modify the latter without affecting the loop:

```
for creature in list(awake):
```

Your biggest problem, however, is that you set `awake` to `self.creatures` at the start of the loop, effectively changing `self.creatures`. Perhaps you meant to use `self.awake` instead?